# Android Navigation Drawer Content

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Can an Android navigation contain a Fragment instead of a listView ?  I'd like to show a sub activity inside of the navigationDrawer ?  The android demo:

[Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

shows only a listview and i've only ever used it with a listview.

Comment: You can have any Viewgroup/View as the Drawer including FrameLayouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a fragment via XML in the [usual way](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).

So, looking at the linked example, you would swap out:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        ... />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        ... />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <fragment android:name="com.example.MyNavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ... />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I suspected so i just wanted sure if the framework allowed it, thanks

Comment: make sure you set `android:clickable="true"` on your fragment otherwise the click events will be passed to your main fragment.